# Adding record to structure in C

Tags: c, struct

I've got structure of Books:

```
 typedef struct {
   int ID;
   char* Title;
 } Book;
```

I just want to add record to Book table. That's my function:

```
void AddRecord(Book**b, int *records_num){

    *records_num = *records_num + 1;

    Book* temp = (Book*)malloc(sizeof(Book) * records_num);
//FirstMethod
    memcpy(temp, *b, records_num * sizeof(Book)); //Doesn't work

    //SecondMethod
    int j;

    for(j = 0; j < records_num - 1; j++){
        temp[j] = (*b)[j];
    }

    free(*b);
    *b = temp;
//Some logic about adding a new record
}
```

Both methods fails after run.
That's how I call this function: **AddRecord(books, &number_of_lines);**
It doesn't work. What's wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I have changed some things in code. It still works bad, but gives no error.

```
void AddRecord(Book *b, int *records_num){

    *records_num = *records_num + 1;

    Book* temp = (Book *)malloc(sizeof(Book) * *records_num);
    memcpy(temp, b, sizeof(b));
    b = (Book *)realloc(b, sizeof(Book) * *records_num);
    memcpy(b, temp, sizeof(temp));
    b[*records_num - 1].ID = *records_num;
}
```

Why this code is wrong?

Comment: Where did you define k and i?

Comment: Are `i` and `k` globally defined? Allocating a global `k` somewhere else and freeing it in this function is a bit precarious. If `i` and `k` are not globally defined, then the code you're showing won't compile. Since you say you've run it, I assume the are global.

Comment: `int *records_num){` records_num is a pointer variable. `malloc(sizeof(Book) * records_num);` here, you use it as if it were an int.

Comment: So, I have to remove * in function's argument? I want to pass int value by reference and add record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, take a look to your structure:

```
 typedef struct {
   int ID;
   char* Title;
 } Book;
```

This structure means that you do not plan to store the title of the book **inside** the struct, but in the heap, by means of *strdup()* or something. If you had planned to store the title whithin the struct, then you would have something like:

```
 typedef struct {
   int ID;
   char Title[100];
 } Book;
```

Both methods have strong and weak points. For example, the second one is more tidy using memory, but it probably wastes a lot of space.

Your code has some stars missing here and there. If you plan to have your vector modified, it is right to pass it as Book **, but then remember that in each use, you will have to put a star before its name. The same happens with num_records. Finally, when you don't have books (the first step), you should not copy or free anything.

```
void addRecord(Book** v, int *records_num, const Book * b)
{
    // Reserve new space and copy
    Book * temp = (Book *) malloc( sizeof(Book) * ( *records_num + 1 ) );

    if ( *v != NULL ) {
        memcpy( temp, *v, ( *records_num ) * sizeof( Book ) );
        free( *v );
    }

    *v = temp;

    // Add new book
    (*v)[ *records_num ].id = b->id;
    (*v)[ *records_num ].title = strdup( b->title );
    ++( *records_num );
}
```

How do you use this? By defining some books and adding them to your collection.

```
int main(void) {
    Book * books = NULL;
    Book b1;
    Book b2;
    Book b3;
    int num = 0;

    // Prepare books
    b1.id = 1;
    b1.title = "Moby Dick";
    b2.id = 2;
    b2.title = "War and peace";
    b3.id = 3;
    b3.title = "Anna Karenina";

    // Add them to the vector
    addRecord( &books, &num, &b1 );
    addRecord( &books, &num, &b2 );
    addRecord( &books, &num, &b3 );

    // Show all books
    showBooks( books, num );

    // Finish
    freeBooks( books, num );
    return 0;
}
```

Remember, anyway, that all those titles will have to be freed before the vector of books is freed. That's done in *freeBooks()*:

```
void freeBooks(Book * v, int num)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(; i < num; ++i) {
        free( v[ i ].title );
    }

    free( v );
}
```

You can access the whole code here:
http://ideone.com/mQQeKi

Hope this helps.